# Pandas : how to merge 2 dataframes on key1.str.endswith(key2)

Tags: python, pandas, merge

i want to find the best way to merge 2 dataframes on key1.str.endswith(key2), an example is sometimes better than words:

```
 i want to merge df1 and df2  on product.str.endswith(color)

 df1:
    index product
    1     a208-BLACK 
    2     a2008-WHITE
    3     x307-PEARL-WHITE
    4     aa-b307-WHITE

 df2:
    index color       code
    1     BLACK       X1001
    2     WHITE       X7005
    3     PEARL-WHITE X7055
```

to get:

```
 df:
    index product            code
    1     a208-BLACK         X1001
    2     a2008-WHITE        X7005
    3     x307-PEARL-WHITE   X7055
    4     aa-b307-WHITE      X7005
```

Any idea ?

Comment: How is the computer to know that `PEARL-WHITE` is a color but `b307-WHITE` is not? Is the capitalization the distinguishing factor?

Comment: I guess so, capitalization let distinguish colors.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a regex expert, the last one was the trickiest one to handle but the following works:

```
In [402]:

df['code'] = df['product'].str.split('-').str[1:].str.join('-').str.findall(r'[A-Z]+').str.join('-').map(df1.set_index('color')['code'])
df
Out[402]:
                product   code
index                         
1            a208-BLACK  X1001
2           a2008-WHITE  X7005
3      x307-PEARL-WHITE  X7055
4         aa-b307-WHITE  X7005
```

Basically I split the product code on `-` and take all the elements to the right of the first dash.

This leaves this:

```
In [403]:

df['product'].str.split('-').str[1:]
Out[403]:
index
1               [BLACK]
2               [WHITE]
3        [PEARL, WHITE]
4         [b307, WHITE]
Name: product, dtype: object
```

I then put the dash back, use a regex to find only uppercase alpha characters, this deals with the last one, rejoin again.

The last bit is to call map on this on the other df after setting the index on the color column, this will perform a lookup on the color value in df and return the corresponding code.

The regex isn't foolproof but it works for your dataset.

**EDIT**

I now realise we don't need that many joins:

```
In [409]:

df['code'] = df['product'].str.findall(r'[A-Z]+').str.join('-').map(df1.set_index('color')['code'])
df
Out[409]:
                product   code
index                         
1            a208-BLACK  X1001
2           a2008-WHITE  X7005
3      x307-PEARL-WHITE  X7055
4         aa-b307-WHITE  X7005
```

**Timings**

```
In [414]:


%%timeit 
import re
df['color'] = df['product'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('^[^ALPHA:]*-(.*)', '\\1', x))

pd.merge(df, df1, on='color')
1 loops, best of 3: 4.09 ms per loop
In [416]:

%%timeit
df['code'] = df['product'].str.findall(r'[A-Z]+').str.join('-').map(df1.set_index('color')['code'])

100 loops, best of 3: 1.63 ms per loop
```

The str method is over 2X faster than using the lambda, this may not be so surprising as the `str` methods are vectorised as is calling `map`.

**Updated timings**

```
In [7]:

%%timeit
df1['color'] = df1['product'].str.extract(r'-([A-Z-]+)$')
pd.merge(df1, df2)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.51 ms per loop
In [9]:

%%timeit
df1['code'] = df1['product'].str.findall(r'[A-Z]+').str.join('-').map(df2.set_index('color')['code'])
100 loops, best of 3: 3.87 ms per loop
In [10]:

%%timeit 
import re
df1['color'] = df1['product'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('^[^ALPHA:]*-(.*)', '\\1', x))

pd.merge(df1, df2, on='color')
100 loops, best of 3: 4.79 ms per loop
```

So @unutbu's answer is marginally faster than @colonel beaveau's but using map here is faster still.

In fact if we combine @unutbu's regex `str` method with map we get faster than my original method:

```
In [12]:

%%timeit
df1['product'].str.extract(r'-([A-Z-]+)$').map(df2.set_index('color')['code'])
100 loops, best of 3: 2.17 ms per loop
```

So using `map` here is nearly 2X faster than merging

Answer (score 1):

Some concise solution:

```
import pandas as pd

df1['color'] = df1['product'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('^[^ALPHA:]*-(.*)', '\\1', x))

pd.merge(df1, df2, on='color')

#            product        color   code
#0        a208-BLACK        BLACK  X1001
#1       a2008-WHITE        WHITE  X7005
#2  x307-PEARL-WHITE  PEARL-WHITE  X7055
#3     aa-b307-WHITE        WHITE  X7005
```

Comment: Color for 3rd row is wrong, you have `WHITE` rather than `PEARL-WHITE`

Comment: Yes just noticed! Will just update the regex. The idea was just to use merge rather than having a very long line ;)

Comment: My method is over 2X faster, surprising given the size of the dataset and the fact I'm performing more operations

Comment: Consiness versus speed, depends on OP choice! I am happy to have found one possible regex still!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [vectorized string method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#text-string-methods), [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.extract.html), with the regex pattern `r'-([A-Z-]+)$'` to find the colors.

```
df1['color'] = df1['product'].str.findall(r'-([A-Z-]+)$').str[0]
```

Then `pd.merge(df1, df2)` will merge on the common column(s) which in this case is the `color` column:

```
result = pd.merge(df1, df2)
```

---

For example,

```
import io
import pandas as pd

df1 = '''\
index product
1     a208-BLACK 
2     a2008-WHITE
3     x307-PEARL-WHITE
4     aa-b307-WHITE'''
df1 = pd.read_table(io.BytesIO(df1), sep='\s+', index_col=0)

df2 = '''\
index color       code
1     BLACK       X1001
2     WHITE       X7005
3     PEARL-WHITE X7055'''
df2 = pd.read_table(io.BytesIO(df2), sep='\s+', index_col=0)
df1['color'] = df1['product'].str.extract(r'-([A-Z-]+)$')
print(pd.merge(df1, df2))
```

yields

```
            product        color   code
0        a208-BLACK        BLACK  X1001
1       a2008-WHITE        WHITE  X7005
2     aa-b307-WHITE        WHITE  X7005
3  x307-PEARL-WHITE  PEARL-WHITE  X7055
```

---

The regex pattern `r'-([A-Z-]+)$'` means

```
-              # match a literal hyphen
(              # followed by a group 
 [A-Z-]+       # of 1-or-more capital letters or hyphens
)              # end of group 
$              # followed by end of line
```