# 'merge' 2 dataframes on elements from list? - double key

Tags: python, string, pandas, list

This is a follow up questions for this one ['merge' 2 dataframes on elements from list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56689519/merge-2-dataframes-on-elements-from-list/56690278#56690278)
The extension is, that now some names can double in df8, so to be able to differntiate between the respective texts, i created a date.

```
df8=pd.DataFrame({'Dates':['2017-12-14', '2017-12-14','2017-12-16'],'names':[['Hans','Meier'],['Debby','Harry'],['Hans','Harry']]})
df9=pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2017-12-14','2017-12-14','2017-12-14','2017-12-14','2017-12-14','2017-12-16','2017-12-16'],'caller':['Hans','Meier','Debby','Harry','Peter','Hans','Harry'],'text':[['hi im hans'],['hi im meier'],['hi im debby'],['hi im harry'],['hi im peter'],['my name is hans'],['my name is harry']]})
df9.set_index(df9.Date, inplace = True)
df9.drop('Date', axis = 1, inplace = True)
df9.head(10)


Date        names    text
2017-12-14  Hans    [hi im hans]
2017-12-14  Meier   [hi im meier]
2017-12-14  Debby   [hi im debby]
2017-12-14  Harry   [hi im harry]
2017-12-14  Peter   [hi im peter]
2017-12-16  Hans    [my name is hans]
2017-12-16  Harry   [my name is harry]
```

the result should be, that the text said by a person in df9 appears in df8 if the person is in the respective list, additionally the names and dates have to match now

so that the output is

```
Date          names                  content
2017-12-14 ['Hans','Meier']          ['hi im hans', 'hi im meier']
2017-12-14 ['Debby','Harry',]        ['hi im debby', 'hi im harry',]
2017-12-16 ['Hans', 'Harry']         ['my name is hans','my name is harry']
```

applying the result from the previous question

```
df9['text']=df9['text'].str[0]
l=[df9.loc[x,'text'].tolist() for x in df8.names]
df8['cont']=l
```

yields this error

> "None of [['Hans', 'Meier']] are in the [index]"

which apperntly has to do with the date index but i dont know how to solve it.
I played a little with the `loc[]` but the error stayed persistant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can do something like:

Flatten the `df8` and assign to `m`

```
m=pd.DataFrame({'Dates':df8.loc[df8.index.repeat(df8.names.str.len()),'Dates'],
         'names':np.concatenate(df8.names)})
```

---

then , `merge` and `groupby`:

```
(m.merge(df9,left_on=['Dates','names'],right_on=['Date','caller']).
groupby('Dates')['text'].apply(sum).reset_index())
```

---

```
        Dates                                 text
0  2017-12-14            [hi im hans, hi im meier]
1  2017-12-15           [hi im debby, hi im harry]
2  2017-12-16  [my name is hans, my name is harry]
```

Comment: this works :) but it has shown me that i forgot an important point in the example: the dates are not exclusive, please have a look on the updated question

Comment: in the updated example it would pull everything on 2017-12-14 into one list, but i need them to remain seperated `0 ['Hans','Meier'] 1['Debby', 'Harry']` and their respective texts

Comment: ok i got it solved... just used another unique key instead of date....
i do want to thank you!!

Comment: @user11638654 okay. I was offline back then. Thanks for the upvote though