# delete tuple if item in tuple not in list in other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, tuples

If i have a list of tuples, and another list on which the tuples should be conditional:

```
my_list=['a','e']
my_list1= ['a','b','a','c','b','d','e','f','a','h']
v=[data for data in zip(my_list1,my_list1[1::1])]
del v[1::2]
```

now to retain only the tuples that contain elemtns from my_list i use

```
v = [tup for tup in v if any(c in my_list for c in tup)]
```

which returns `[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('e', 'f'), ('a', 'h')]`

now i want to perform the same operation iterating over dataframes

```
df15=pd.DataFrame({'names':[['a','c'],['k','f']]})
df14=pd.DataFrame({'tup':[[('a','g'), ('b','h'), ('c', 'i')],[('d', 'j'), ('e', 'k'), ('f', 'l')]]})
```

but calling

```
for index,row in df14.iterrows():
df15['tup']=[tup for tup in df14['tup'] if any(c in df15.names for c in tup)]
```

returns this error:

> Length of values does not match length of index

expected output would be

```
 df15    
            names     tup
    0     ['a','c']  [('a','g'),('c', 'i')] #not necessary to keep the tuples
    1     ['k','f']  [('e', 'k'),('f','l')]
```

Comment: Why do you have tuples and lists in your dataframe? It beats the whole purpose of pandas.

Comment: because i am new to python and this is the only way i can think of how to handle my data.

Comment: @Erfan alternatively my code would work if i find an answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56709889/merge-2-dataframes-on-elements-from-list-double-key)