# How to append a list of elements into a single feature of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops, dataframe

I have two dataframes, a df of actors who have a feature that is a list of movie identifier numbers for films that they've worked on. I also have a list of movies that have an identifier number that will show up in the actor's list if the actor was in that movie.

I've attempted to iterate through the movies dataframe, which does produce results but is too slow.

It seems like iterating through the list of movies from the actors dataframe would result in less looping, but I've been unable to save results.

Here is the actors dataframe:

```
print(actors[['primaryName', 'knownForTitles']].head())
         primaryName                           knownForTitles
0     Rowan Atkinson  tt0109831,tt0118689,tt0110357,tt0274166
1        Bill Paxton  tt0112384,tt0117998,tt0264616,tt0090605
2   Juliette Binoche  tt1219827,tt0108394,tt0116209,tt0241303
3   Linda Fiorentino  tt0110308,tt0119654,tt0088680,tt0120655
4  Richard Linklater  tt0243017,tt1065073,tt2209418,tt0405296
```

And the movies dataframe:

```
print(movies[['tconst', 'primaryTitle']].head())
      tconst                 primaryTitle
0  tt0001604            The Fatal Wedding
1  tt0002467          Romani, the Brigand
2  tt0003037   Fantomas: The Man in Black
3  tt0003593  Across America by Motor Car
4  tt0003830       Detective Craig's Coup
```

As you can see, the `movies['tconst']` identifier shows up in a list in the actors dataframe.

My very slow iteration through the movie dataframe is as follows:

```
def add_cast(movie_df, actor_df):

    results = movie_df.copy()
    length = len(results)

    #create an empty feature 
    results['cast'] = ""

    #iterate through the movie identifiers
    for index, value in results['tconst'].iteritems():
        #create a new dataframe containing all the cast associated with the movie id
        cast = actor_df[actor_df['knownForTitles'].str.contains(value)]


        #check to see if the 'primaryName' list is empty
        if len(list(cast['primaryName'].values)) != 0:
            #set the new movie 'cast' feature equal to a list of the cast names
            results.loc[index]['cast'] = list(cast['primaryName'].values)

        #logging
        if index % 1000 == 0:
            logging.warning(f'Results location: {index} out of {length}')

        #delete cast df to free up memory
        del cast

    return results
```

This generates some results but is not fast enough to be useful. One observation is that by creating a new dataframe of all the actors who have the movie identifier in their `knownForTitles` is that this list can be put into a single feature of the movies dataframe.

Whereas for my attempt to loop through the actors dataframe below, I don't seem to be able to append items into the movies dataframe:

```
def actors_loop(movie_df, actor_df):

    results = movie_df.copy()
    length = len(actor_df)


    #create an empty feature 
    results['cast'] = ""

    #iterate through all actors
    for index, value in actor_df['knownForTitles'].iteritems():


        #skip empties
        if str(value) == r"\N":
            logging.warning(f'skipping: {index} with a value of {value}')
            continue

        #generate a list of movies that this actor has been in
        cinemetography = [x.strip() for x in value.split(',')]

        #iterate through every movie the actor has been in
        for movie in cinemetography:

            #pull out the movie info if it exists
            movie_info = results[results['tconst'] == movie]

            #continue if empty
            if len(movie_info) == 0:
                continue

            #set the cast variable equal to the actor name
            results[results['tconst'] == movie]['cast'] = (actor_df['primaryName'].loc[index])

            #delete the df to save space ?maybe
            del movie_info

        #logging
        if index % 1000 == 0:
            logging.warning(f'Results location: {index} out of {length}')

    return results
```

So if I run the above code, I get a very fast result, but the 'cast' field remains empty.

Comment: none of the `tconst` in movies is there in actors `knownForTitles` in the example

Comment: yes that's correct. matches are rare but I performed several test cases that included a definite match. Should I include that code?

Comment: No , just edit the input data so that they are in sync, if possible add a expected data too. :) bdw check this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56689519/merge-2-dataframes-on-elements-from-list/56689677#56689677 i think you  have kinda same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem I was having with `def actors_loop(movie_df, actor_df)` function. The problem is that

`results['tconst'] == movie]['cast'] = (actor_df['primaryName'].loc[index])`

is setting the value equal to a copy of the `results` dataframe. It would be better to use the `df.set_value()` method or the `df.at[]` method.

I also figured out a much faster solution to the problem, rather than iterate through two dataframes and create recursive looping, it would be better to iterate once. So I created a list of tuples:

```
def actor_tuples(actor_df):
    tuples =[]
    for index, value in actor_df['knownForTitles'].iteritems():

        cinemetography = [x.strip() for x in value.split(',')]
        for movie in cinemetography:
            tuples.append((actor_df['primaryName'].loc[index], movie))
    return tuples
```

This created a list of tuples of the following form:

```
[('Fred Astaire', 'tt0043044'),
 ('Lauren Bacall', 'tt0117057')]
```

I then created a list of movie identifier numbers and index points (from the movie dataframe), that took this form:

```
{'tt0000009': 0,
 'tt0000147': 1,
 'tt0000335': 2,
 'tt0000502': 3,
 'tt0000574': 4,
 'tt0000615': 5,
 'tt0000630': 6,
 'tt0000675': 7,
 'tt0000676': 8,
 'tt0000679': 9}
```

I then used the below function to iterate through the actor tuples and use the movie identifier as the key in the movie dictionary, this returned the correct movie index, which I used to add the actor name tuple to the target dataframe:

```
def add_cast(movie_df, Atuples, Mtuples):
    results_df = movie_df.copy()
    results_df['cast'] = ''
    counter = 0
    total = len(Atuples)


    for tup in Atuples:
        #this passes the movie ID into the movie_dict that will return an index
        try:
            movie_index = Mtuples[tup[1]]
            if results_df.at[movie_index, 'cast'] == '':
                results_df.at[movie_index, 'cast'] += tup[0]
            else:
                results_df.at[movie_index, 'cast'] += ',' + tup[0]
        except KeyError:
            pass

        #logging
        counter +=1
        if counter % 1000000 == 0:
            logging.warning(f'Index {counter} out of {total}, {counter/total}% finished')

    return results_df
```

It ran in 10 minutes (making 2 sets of tuples, then the adding function) for 16.5 million actor tuples. The results are below:

```
0  tt0000009                     Miss Jerry      1894                 Romance   
1  tt0000147  The Corbett-Fitzsimmons Fight      1897  Documentary,News,Sport   
2  tt0000335          Soldiers of the Cross      1900         Biography,Drama   
3  tt0000502                       Bohemios      1905                      \N   
4  tt0000574    The Story of the Kelly Gang      1906   Biography,Crime,Drama   

                                                cast  
0  Blanche Bayliss,Alexander Black,William Courte...  
1  Bob Fitzsimmons,Enoch J. Rector,John L. Sulliv...  
2  Herbert Booth,Joseph Perry,Orrie Perry,Reg Per...  
3  Antonio del Pozo,El Mochuelo,Guillermo Perrín,...  
4  Bella Cola,Sam Crewes,W.A. Gibson,Millard John...
```

Thank you stack overflow!